# ASP.NET MVC 4 +.NET 4.5 - Using dots in the middle of the parameters - and avoid RAMMFAR

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, asp.net-mvc-routing

is there any solution to use points/dots in the middle of a parameter with ASP.NET MVC 4, .NET 4.5 and IIS 7.5?
Examples:

- http://www.mydomain.com/Users/FirstName.LastName fails
- http://www.mydomain.com/Users/FirstName.LastName/ works, if the URL is not generated by Url.RouteUrl
- http://www.mydomain.com/Users/FirstName.LastName/Edit works

I know why this happens, but all workarounds (Handlers, relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping) I've found are perfect if the dot is at the end of the url - but in this case the only solution I've found is to activate RAMMFAR (and use another CDN Server for my static content).
Because the depth of the parameter with the dot is dynamic the handler-solution fails, too.

Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: At this point I'd be asking myself: is the dot really worth it?

Comment: Here it's a simple example. In my case: yes: it's required.

Answer (score 0):

I've created my own Route and overriden GetVirtualPath to get a trailing slash if required.